# Sling Merger Comments

Tags: aem, sling

i'm curious about html comments in a page source, i can find such html comments on all pages system, or wich were created by ourselves. I guess that it comment't for sling merger or so on.
[image]

We use AEM 6.2.0 with acs commons 3.3.0, i guess it for dev's mode of something else, but i can't find how to turn it of.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that it's the `WCM Developer Mode Filter`. Try disabling it from the OSGi console and see if the output disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have enabled the xray mode of TouchUI as per the document at:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/troubleshooting-aem-touchui-issues.html

You can disable this feature by deleting the node at: /etc/xraymode/enable